# How to run C main program in XCode project that is not a Command Line Project

Tags: xcode

[image]I need to run a .c main() program from xCode.   I have created project and it compiles FINE.  The problem is the RUN is greyed out!!!  No reason given. Nice default behavior. Whats the problem here?  I'm running xCode 5.0.

Update:  Ok, I am able to run hello.c it if its a Command Line Project. But the problem is I am working with a large project that is not a Command Line Project/

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Opts7.jpg">

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your active scheme to the one with the correct target.

[image]